# CloudFront doesn't return CORS headers for S3 subfolders

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

For my CloudFront distribution config, i've set `Response headers policy` to include the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

However i only noticed some assets served from CloudFront (which serves them from S3) include this header while others aren't.

e.g `https://cloudfront.net/app/componentA.js` includes this header while `https://cloudfront.net/app/folder/componentB.js` doesn't.

Is there something i'm missing?